# Android: Intent is not working onClick

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick

so i am a beginner with programming and basicly just self-teaching everything.
I have managed a few things to work but now I am having the following issue:

Scenario: 
I have 2 Activities. In one activity i click a button. `onClick` it should retreive text in string format from a textfile in the assets folder and send it to the next activity , and show the string in it's `textView` field.

The problem:
that i now have is: I can click the button, it does open the next activity but i don't see any text.
And i can't really figure out what is going wrong. I tried to set a `breakline` on the button while debugging it but i cannot make any sence of the info that the debugger is throwing at me. :(

I have the following code:

Activity 1:
IndoorMenuActivity.java

```
public class IndoorMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indoor_menu);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button66);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(IndoorMenuActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
            String text = "";

            try{
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                text = new String(buffer);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, text);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Activity 2: 
ViewActivity.java

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.myapp.MESSAGE");

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

And my manifest file:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GeneralInformationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".IndoorMenuActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OutdoorMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DatabaseMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ToolsMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

I have no clue on how to solve this or where to even look for the right information, so I can see where I've gone wrong. I just mangled and slashed code together and somehow got most of it working. but with this deeper stuff i'm basically lost.
And to make it a bit more difficult: i don't exactly know any standard programming practices or terms that come with that so some simple explanation and help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: check your logcat

Comment: You should check following step:
1. Set directly `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "this is test message");` to make sure basic code work
2. Read your log (Android Monitor on IDE ), it will show stackTrace if there any exception occurs due to your file (not exist, wrong path, permisson....)
3. Check your layout text box whether its' value is reset anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have got some error messages and posted them below in a reply.

Answer (score 1):

In `ViewActivity.java` everything look good, so I say debug your `IndoorMenuActivity.java`.
Learn to work with Log, this help debug your code:
Place `Log.e("MY_TEXT", "text=" + text);` after `text = new String(buffer);`
Then check the Android Monitor and look for the "MY_TEXT", it will be in red.
If you don't see it, that would mean something went wrong while reading the file, now add another Log: `Log.e("MY_TEXT", "below is the error");` this time, before the `ex.printStackTrace();`
To sum up:

```
try{
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            text = new String(buffer);
            Log.e("MY_TEXT", "text=" + text);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
           `Log.e("MY_TEXT", "below is the error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i get the eroors but

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some issue while you reading the content from InputStream. Please check the exception(in Catch block) in Log and check that again. If any error there please use this code for read data from InputStream

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, just call me stupid. -.-
I found the error... 
i misttyped the string of InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt")

I edited the text out for this forum but upon reading the code i just noticed i forgot to make the first letter in the stringpath with a capital as i did in the assetfolder.

Anyways verry mucht thanks for the infromation and help.
It works now as it's supposed to do.